# Sublime text 3: possible to bind to multiple (sequential) keypresses?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm giving Sublimetext 3 a go as a long time VIM user. One thing I'm wondering is if there is a way to bind to multiple sequential keys. In VIM I have used `imap hh =>` which lets me type 2 `h`'s in sequence and get a `=>`. Is there any way to set this up in ST3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keys` key in a key binding is a JSON `list` and can contain multiple keys that must be hit in sequence in order for the binding to activate. For example, the default key binding for opening the Sidebar (on Windows/Linux) is declared as the following, requiring you to press <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd>:

```json
    { 
        "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+b"], 
        "command": "toggle_side_bar" 
    },
```

It's also possible to bind unmodified keys as well, such as `"h"` (although you cannot bind just a modifier by itself like `"ctrl"`), so for your purposes you can do something like the following:

[EDIT] Starting with ST4, you can indeed bind just a modifier key if desired. [/EDIT]

```json
    {
        "keys": ["h", "h"],
        "command": "insert",
        "args": {
            "characters": "=>"
        },
    },

    {
        "keys": ["h", "i"],
        "command": "insert",
        "args": {
            "characters": "->"
        },
    },
```

These use the built in `insert` command to insert a specific set of text; this command is smart enough to ensure that the insertion happens at all carets in the file. As seen in this example you can have multiple such keys defined if you like as well.

Note however that a key binding such as this sample is somewhat naive in that it will block you from actually typing these characters in a row, such as that second example effectively blocking you from typing the word `this` without waiting a bit after entering the `h` to allow Sublime to time out the key chord.

To get around that you can employ a [context](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-context) of some sort that constrains the availability of that key binding.

If you take advantage of some Vim type package for Sublime such as [NeoVintageous](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/NeoVintageous) they would also allow you to use more `vi`-like bindings directly as well.